# Laravel Eloquent retrieving data with 'with' and finding based on values in this 'with'

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

So I have a Players table and Loans table.

```
Players
id | name | age

Loans
id | player_id (foreign key) | status
```

I can get all players and their loans by using this:

```
Player::with('loans')->paginate(15);
```

Now I want to list all players where the loans status is certain value, how do I do that?

Something like:

```
Player::with('loans')->where('loans.status',$status)->paginate(15);
```

Comment: As in you want to get all players and then only get loans when the loan is a certain status or you only want to get players that have loan(s) with a certain status?

Comment: I want to get players data AND loans data within each player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `whereHas` for this:

```
Player::whereHas('loans', function ($q) use ($status) {
    $q->where('status', $status);
})->paginate(15);
```

This is querying based on the existence of a relationship.

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)